# Microsoft VisualStudio 2010 c++ vector iterator.base not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use next constuctioon in my code:

```
for (std::vector<Process>::iterator iter = processesExecutuions->begin(); iter != processesExecutuions->end(); ++iter) {
    if (iter.base()->id == id) {
        return iter.base();
    }
}
```

But VisualStudio during compilation throw error:
error C2039: 'base' : is not a member of 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>'

When I use make with g++ in my Ubuntu everything is ok.
Could you clarify how to solve this problem in msvs?

Comment: Why do you use _base()_ with iterator? That is a member of _reverse_iterator_ not iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are relying on `std::vector::<T>iterator` being a type with a member function `base`. You cannot make such assumptions about the actual type of a container iterator. The iterator could be implemented in many ways, as long as it satisfies [certain requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).

In the case of `std::vector`, iterators are *random access iterators*, and could even be implemented as a plain pointers on some platforms. So do not rely on implementation details of iterators: these are not portable.

**Note**: If you want to access `Process::base` instead of `std::vector<T>::iterator::base`, then you need `iter->base()` instead of `iter.base()`.